# Im trying to create a PHP online direct messaging system. I don't know how to show responses when they send a message without refreshing page

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

I don't know how to allow the user to see when a user has sent a message without refreshing the entire page and calling a query to check out what the message is. I currently just show the messages from a SELECT * FROM tableName and only show content from one column. but I Can't display messages once I send a message or once the person the user is talking to sends a message.

Comment: Take a look at [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular's suggestion is great (using web sockets).   An alternative: call by ajax to the db say every 5 seconds (and also do such ajax immediately after you submit a new message) to get updated messages and put onto say a DIV to display. In this way both the new message submitted by you and other people will be seen in a timely manner.